# Memory and speed performance of gather in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a hierarchical softmax while I have some performance issues with `gather` in tensorflow, both from meomory and speed. Here is an example:

```
# weights_word: [nClusters, hiddenSize, max_cluster_size]
weights_word = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.textData.nClusters, self.args.hiddenSize, self.textData.max_cluster_size], stddev=0.5, dtype=self.dtype), name='weights_word', dtype=self.dtype)

# target_cluster: [batchSize, maxSteps]
# weights_gathered: [batchSize, maxSteps, hiddenSize, max_cluster_size]
weights_gathered = tf.gather(weights_word, self.target_cluster, name='weights_gathered')
```

where I need to gather weights for different class words in the second level of my hierarchical softmax. But the `gather` operation seems to be a very expensive one. It creates a temporary variable `weights_gathered`, which even consumes more memory than original `weights_word`. Besides, when using timeline to profile my program, I find `gather` is very time consuming. I am wondering if there are any way that I can optimize this both in speed and memory.

Comment: If you insist on using `gather`, I don't think there's much to be done. On the other hand, you may be able to adapt your implementation so it doesn't use a `gather`, e.g. if you have a regular tree structure, you may be able to acheive equivalent values with a reshape or two. Without more details about your algorithm it's hard to say much more.